# Changing date formats for display and edit in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have the following column model defined -

```js
{
    name: 'from',
    index: 'from',
    formatter: 'date',
    formatoptions: {srcformat:'ISO8601Long', newformat:'d-M-y H:i'},
    editable: true,
    edittype: 'text',
    editoptions: {
        maxlengh: 16,
        dataInit: function(element) {
            $(element).datetimepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm',
                separator: ' ',
                timezone: '000'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The date is being correctly formatted as "d-M-y H:i" when displayed in the grid.  When I try to edit a record the form is populated with the date in this format but I would like it to be 'Y-m-d H:i' for editing.  If I make a change using the datetimepicker then the value is updated to the desired format but if the value is not edited the value posted is "d-M-y H:i" format.

How would I go about changing the format of the date before it is written to the form field?  Can I access the formatting methods used by jqGrid for conversion?  Can I use the unformat option to convert before the form field is populated?  I have tried various combinations but to no avail.

Comment: Did one of the answers below help you on your solution? If so please mark one as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the colModel that worked for me. The key was removing my "date: true" edit rule, and dateformat as well, that I normally have in place for regular datepicker columns. Also, getting the format model just right is always a PITA. I have this set to what my users like and what my Oracle DB works best with...this was trial and error and used this page as reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

```
{
name:"WMBEMSG_BEGIN_DATE", 
align:"center", 
index:"WMBEMSG_BEGIN_DATE", 
datefmt: 'mm/dd/Y HH:MM', 
editable: true, 
edittype: "text", 
editoptions: { dataInit: function(el) { $(el).datetimepicker({
    controlType: 'select',
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
                        timeFormat: "HH:mm"
  } ) }
   }, 
label:"Begin Date", 
width:50, 
sortable: true
}
```

Also, be sure your timepicker javascript include is AFTER your jquery and jquery UI loads.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom format function to modify the value, and then the custom unformat option for when that value is transmitted.

```
formatter: customFormatFunctionName,

unformat: customUnformatFunctionName,
```

Functions:

```
function customFormatFunctionName(cellval, opts, rowObject, action) { ...

function customUnformatFunctionName(cellval, opts, rowObject, action) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should just use `dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy'` instead of `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'` and `timeFormat: 'HH:mm'` instead of `timeFormat: 'hh:mm'`. It corresponds to format `newformat:'d-M-y H:i'` which you use.

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DateTimepicker.htm):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the end I opted for enforcing what I consider to be a sane (unambiguous) format 'yyyy-mm-dd' at all levels. I was hoping the "native" formatters would behave as most custom formatters would by reverting formats for edit using unformat.