# how to write time picker field in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

how to add time picker field in jqgrid ...This is my code here how to add time picker filed in jqgrid

These are the import files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/redmond/jquery.ui.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-1.4.3.css">
 <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="js/grid-search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-1.4.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


{name:'joinDate',index:'joinDate',width:4.5,
            editable:true,editoptions:{size:12,
                dataInit:function(elem){
                $(elem).datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                    timeFormat: 'H:mm',});
                },
        defaultValue: function(){
                var currentTime = new Date();
                var month = parseInt(currentTime.getMonth() + 1);
                month = month <= 9 ? "0"+month : month;
                var day = currentTime.getDate();
                day = day <= 9 ? "0"+day : day;
                var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                return year+"-"+month + "-"+day;                
                }},
                editrules:{required:true},
            formatoptions: {srcformat:'ISO8601Long', newformat:'d-M-y H:i'}},
```

Any one Please reply me

Thanks in adavance

Comment: it's important to know which format have **input data** which you use to fill the grid and in which format you what **display** the data to the user. You display currently `yyyy-mm-dd` in the edit form and uses `'dd-mm-yy'` as the option of jQuery UI Datepicker.

Comment: @oleg Thanks for reply ..ya i did worng format now i correct it ...that is date format datepicker ..how can i write timepicker in the grid ??

Comment: @oleg thanks for reply ..i got jquery plugin in that they given code like' $('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker();'  they given library files about datetimepicker ..#means they taken id how can i give id in col names please reply me for this

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery UI plugin [Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) for example which allows to implement either pure `timepicker` or `datetimepicker`. You need just replace the usage of `$(el).datepicker` to `$(el).datetimepicker` and include the options of `datetimepicker`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DateTimepicker1.htm) for example is small modification of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DateTimepicker.htm) which I created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15451805/315935). It demonstrate how `datetimepicker` can be used.

Comment: thanks for your reply ..  thank you so much.....and how to give 'dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy''  This is the date format but how to give datetime format ???

Comment: @manasvi: You are welcome! You don't described which format have input data and which for displaying to the user. [My demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DateTimepicker1.htm) shows an example of the usage of `dateFormat` and `timeFormat`. I used `dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"`. The format of `dateFormat` described in [Datepicker documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate). If you use `formatter:'date'` you should use `srcformat` and `newformat` of `formatoptions` additionally.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,,,am poor in jquery sorry for the asking this doubt  but i didnt get output that's why am asking ..'datepicker({dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'})' replace to 'datetimepicker({dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'})' imported library files related files also ..what happen in my code please reply me for this answer

Comment: @manasvi: I wrote you before that I need to know **exact format of input the date and the exact format of displayed data**. For example I used in my demo `"2007-12-02T23:07:36"`. So I used `formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d/m/Y H:i" }` and ` dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", timeFormat: "HH:mm"`. You asked: "what happen in my code" *without* posting important information which I need. If you don't specified `srcformat` and `newformat` of `formatoptions` then the locale file `grid.locale-XX.js` (like `grid.locale-de.js`) is important. Could you post the info?

Comment: @manasvi: I asked you multiple times about the exact format of input data for the column `dateOfBirth` which you use. Could you answer on my question? By the way, you should not post an answer on your own question if you want to include additional information. Instead of that you should click "edit" link under the question and modify the text of your question. One *append* typically the original text with words like "Update:" and new information. In the code which you posted you included jqGrid multiple times (jquery.jqGrid.src.js and jquery.jqGrid.src-fixed-dragStart.js) which is wrong.

Comment: kk i never post the answer for my question sorry for  my mistake..'dd/mm/yy' i used this format for date and time 'HH:mm'..i remove you mentioned import files also...if you dont mind can you send me the source code of that datetimepicker include files also ...i tried so many ways but i didnt get any output

Comment: @manasvi: Sorry, but could you clear answer on the questions which I asked many many times before: **which is exact format of input data for the column `'date'`**? **In which format should be displayed the data in the column?** For example in the demo which I posted input data `"2007-09-06T07:17:12"` will be displayed as "06-Sep-2007 07:17".

Comment: ohh sorry for that ..."12/12/2013 4:58pm"   This format i want

Comment: @manasvi: Is it the format of **input data** or **you want display the data in the format**?

Comment: Thank you so much i got output

Comment: hii oleg .Your replys answers awesome...i got one doubt can i ask ??? Thanks in adavance

Comment: @manasvi: You can directly ask your question instead of asking whether you can ask it. :-) What is your question?

Comment: your demo working in client side excellent ..but the same code put in server side (javaEE)(JSP pages) .In the server side not displayed datetime, the main problem is library files(jquery.min.js ,,jquery-ui.min.js),

Comment: you gave url,i imported same library files in the server side in that time it's working but it's not correct way to import url's in the server side so that why i copied code put in the server side when i copied imported those library files in that datetime not displayed(becz those two file (jquery.min.js ,,jquery-ui.min.js) are some errors so server not taken 2 files).Can you Please reply me, what is the mistake i did????

Comment: @manasvi: first you should use correct order of JavaScript files and no duplicates. `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` depends on jQuery so either `jquery.js` or `jquery.min.js` have to be included *before*. You can't include both `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` or both `jquery.js` and `jquery.min.js`. `grid.locale-en.js` should be included before `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`). You don't need include `jquery.ui.theme.css` if you included `jquery-ui.css` before.

Comment: @manasvi: Seconds you should verify that the server returns date in the correct format. The format have to corresponds to `formatoptions.srcformat`. If you use `'ISO8601Long'` then the date have to be string like `"2007-09-06T07:17:12"` or `"2007-09-06 07:17:12"`. You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler), "Network" part of Developer Tools of Internet Explorer (press F12 to start) to catch HTTP traffic between the client and the server. You should find the server respond with JSON input data and verify the format of date.

Comment: hiii i follow you mentioned format ,but i used in one page total 5 grids ,,but when the datetimepicker code used in that time remaning 4 grids are not working ..please help me .  Thanks,,,